# Read from a file and turn contents to dictionary

Tags: python

I have a text file with its contents written as follows:

```
State Texas
Austin
 Houston
 Dallas
State Florida
Orlando
Miami
Jacksonville
Naples
!
State California
San Diego
Los Angeles
San Francisco
```

Goal: I want to read from this text file and turn them into dictionary and should look like this -

```
state_dict = {
    'Texas': ['Austin', 'Houston', 'Dallas'], 
    'Florida': ['Orlando', 'Miami', 'Jacksonville', 'Naples'], 
    'California': ['San Diego', 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco']
}
```

So far my code is this:

```
State_Dict = {}
with open('state.txt', 'r') as main_fd:

for mystate in main_fd:
    mystate = mystate.lstrip()

    if ("State" in mystate):
        state_key = "_".join(mystate.split()[1:])
        State_Dict[state_key] = []

        for cities in main_fd:
            if ("!" in cities):
                break

            else:
                State_Dict[state_key].append(cities.rstrip())

print(State_Dict)
```

But the output is this:

```
{
'Texas': [
    ' Austin', ' Houston', ' Dallas', 
    'State Florida', ' Orlando', ' Miami', 
    ' Jacksonville', ' Naples'
    ], 
'California': [
    ' San Diego', ' Los Angeles', ' San Francisco'
    ]
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: The problem is that you break out of a loop when you occur "!" and not when new line start's with "State"

Comment: If I don't break out of the loop when "!" occurs it is going to get added as a value which I don't want to happen.

Comment: In that case use `continue` instead of `break`.

Comment: There is another command called `continue` which just skips executing the rest of that part of the loop and continues with the next variable in the `iterator`. What `break` does is terminate the loop completely. Try changing it to `continue` and see if that resolves it.

Comment: main_fd is your file object or iterator or whatnot, you need to get this code into a 1 loop solution. your inner loop gets hit and exhausts the file object because "cities" doesnt really mean anything to the computer, and it just iterates all the lines in the inner loop. (until it hits break anyways) This is why Florida and its cities get added to texas.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the real problem. Notice that State Florida is added on as a value to the key Texas. I need to get "Florida" as a key. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. @ParitoshSingh - can you please show me the 1 loop solution for this?

Comment: Alright, one sec.

Comment: What's the point of the `!` in the input? It's not necessary to mark the end of a city list; the start of the next state does that just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is something like this.
Consider the loop iterating through one line at a time, and build a series of checks for your conditions. PS. Let me know if this doesn't work, wrote it without testing.

```
State_Dict = {}

with open('state.txt', 'r') as main_fd:
    for line in main_fd:
        line = line.strip() #left and right stripped    
        #if ("state" in line.lower()): #better version suggested in comments to handle 'state' and 'State'.
        if ("State" in line):
            state_key = "_".join(line.split()[1:])
            State_Dict[state_key] = []
        elif ("!" in line):
            continue #goes to next iteration of loop instead of stopping the loop unlike break
        else: #assuming last case
            State_Dict[state_key].append(line) #line has already been stripped

print(State_Dict)
```

Comment: Wow I just realize your answer is exactly the same as my edit... what are the chances... maybe I should just remove mine then.

Comment: The only thing I would change, is to add some error-handling of the data and instead write `if "state" in line.lower()`, to match both `"State"` and `"state"`

Comment: Aye definitely. This should be taken as a minimal example and one should add things as required. I'll edit it in.

Comment: @ParitoshSingh - so the code works if the file has the exact data from the example above. It seems to crap out when there is an empty line or another set of lines with words above the original data. For example, before line "State Texas", if some other line exist like "Places you should visit" the error message pops up - NameError: name 'state_key' is not defined. I was hoping that it would only grab lines that are relevant to my dictionary.

Comment: so, first step is to figure out why it craps out. (hint, look at the else block). Next, you'd have to think of what you can do to handle whatever scenarios are being hit that should also be skipped over. (hint, continued over). @vmx1987

Answer (score 0):

The problems with you code were that you were stopping looking for cities of a state when you occurred "!" but new portion of cities also were indicated by line starting with "State". 
Another bug was that you iterated for cities from beginning every time instead of state you're currently at.

```
State_Dict = {}
main_fd = '''\
State Texas
Austin
Houston
Dallas
State Florida
Orlando
Miami
Jacksonville
Naples
!
State California
San Diego
Los Angeles
San Francisco\
'''.splitlines()

for idx, mystate in enumerate(main_fd):
    if "State" in mystate:
        state_key = "_".join(mystate.split()[1:])
        State_Dict[state_key] = []

        for cities in main_fd[idx+1:]:
            if '!' in cities or "State" in cities:
                break

            else:
                State_Dict[state_key].append(cities.rstrip())

print(State_Dict)
```

output:

```
{'Florida': ['Orlando', 'Miami', 'Jacksonville', 'Naples'], 
'California': ['San Diego', 'Los Angeles', 'San Francisco'], 
'Texas': ['Austin', 'Houston', 'Dallas']}
```